# Changing a date format

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

To convert year column and month column to date column in Tableau

**Sample data:**

**year**    **Month**

2014    aug

2014    sep

2013    oct

**Expected Date**

aug-2014

sep-2014

oct-2013

Please help to solve this.

Comment: [How to change date-format in Tableau](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/fixing-date-fields) and [How to format numbers & dates](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/formatting-numbers-and-dates)

Comment: The question header is really interesting,but the question isn't! formatting its inbuilt facility available in `tableau`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str([Month])+ "-" +str([Year])
```

Create duplicate field and using `str` function to add the two fields. But this was not help has date field.

Answer (score 1):

There is a create calculated field option in tableau.
In that you can use various functions. Here you can use `str` function and `month` and `year` functions in tableau.
you can write `Str(Month[Date])+"-"+Str(Year[date])` this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the formatting. There is a custom option in the formatting which allows you to change that ( go to format- custom and you can type: mmm-yyyy) and you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what is happening, you have individual string values that represent month/year.

You need to convert these into inputs for a calculated field to create the date.  Try creating a field called `Year_Calc = LEFT([raw data field], 4)`.

To create a month field you will have to take the month values out using `Month_Calc = RTRIM(RIGHT([raw data field],4))` assuming the months have 3 or 4 values.  Then put the Month_Calc into a case statement so that you assign string month values to the corresponding month number.

You can wrap the original equation into this if you want.

```
CASE RTRIM(RIGHT([raw data field],4))
WHEN "jan" THEN 1
WHEN "feb" THEN 2
....
WHEN "dec" THEN 12
END
```

Take these two fields and put them into the following DATE function to create a date. `DATE(STR(Year_Calc) + "/" + STR(Month_Calc) + "/" + STR(1))`

There are ways to shorten it up a bit to run a bit more efficiently - but without seeing the data its hard to tell.

Answer (score -1):

If your data is in mySQL than I would be using that to join the columns together in a date format before you use it in Tableau. Possibly using this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry, still getting the hang of using SO, but I thought I did put in the essential parts and then the link ... no ?